# Return 401 instead of redirecting identityserver

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I use ASP.NET Core for an api and can not find a way to configure identity to return a 401 instead of redirecting to the login page. I use the IdentityServerAuthentication Middleware.

In the Startup.cs, I give these options:

```
        var options = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Authority"),
            ScopeName = "scopeName",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

        };
        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(options);
```

Comment: did you try set AutomaticChallenge = false on IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions?

Comment: I tried it and it's not solving the problem.

Comment: Did you try adding an  `AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/")` to your authentication?

Comment: yes I tried and it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find a solution,
In the request, you can add a header X-Requested-With with a value of XMLHttpRequest. 
This will tell identity to not redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite the default behavior redirecting to identity server when unauthorized, we had to create a custom Authorize class implementing `System.Web.MVC.AuthorizeAttribute`.  Then, in the case that the user was unauthorized (but logged in via identity server) we showed the user an unauthorized page.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext                 
filterContext)
{
if (filterContext == null) {
   throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
}

//Intercept results where person is authenticated but still doesn't have 
permissions
if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(ConfigSettings.KPToolsURL + 
    "/Error/HttpError401");
    return;
}

base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

I wrote a blog post about it in which I go into more detail https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/07/09/identityserver-auth-mvc/.